# Why is my while loop ending?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, return, response

It doesn't matter whether I put Y or N, my program ends after I answer "More meat?" I'm expecting it to return the response to the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char response = 'y';
    double price;
    double total = 0;
    while (response == 'Y' || 'y') {

        cout << "Please enter price of meat: ";
        cin >> price;

        total += price;

        cout << "More meat? (Y/N)";
        cin >> response;
        return response;
    }
    cout << "Your total is: " << total;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: (response == 'Y' || 'y') should be (response == 'Y' || response =='y')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (response == 'Y' || 'y') {
```

should be

```
while (response == 'Y' || response ==  'y') {
```

Also

```
return response;
```

exits the whole function (`main`). You don't need it.

---

> I'm expecting it to return the response to the loop

You don't need to ( `return` is used for returning a value from a function, terminating its execution). So, after `}` of the loop, the next executed line will be `while ( condition ) ...`. If `condition` is evaluated to `false`, the loop will stop and the next executed line will be the one, after the loop's `}`.

Comment: ironically the condition of the while loop is irrelevant to why it is exiting as the condition as written is basically a `while(true)` loop. The `return` is the actual answer.

Comment: @Mgetz - true, but still both things are a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is broken, as is your `while()` test and you have a spurious `return` statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char response = 'y';
    double price;
    double total = 0;
    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y') {

        cout << "Please enter price of meat: ";
        cin >> price;

        total += price;

        cout << "More meat? (Y/N)";
        cin >> response;
    } // end while
    cout << "Your total is: " << total;

    return 0;
} // end main()
```

(Using `do ... while()` would be slightly neater as well as you wouldn't need to initialize `response` to `'y'`).